# How extensive should a single unit test be?

Tags: c, unit-testing, glib

I writing an application in `C`. I am new to writing unit tests. I will be using the `glib` testing framework.

I read this [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing) in wikipedia. I am unsure of what my unit tests should cover.

I know that my unit test should check whether for a valid input, the expected result is obtained. Is this all that needs to be done while writing a unit test for a function?

Should I also check the value of each variable every time it is modified? Because if the functionality is extended, then more variables might be added and current variables might be modified at various other places, so then I will have to change the test itself.

Please give me your input.

Comment: Here is a joke which should give you a hint : "QA Engineer walks into a bar. Orders a beer. Orders 0 beers. Orders 999999999 beers. Orders a lizard. Orders -1 beers. Orders a sfdeljkn." :-)

Comment: @AlexMarandon and then there's the [serious side](http://www.rbcs-us.com/documents/Why-Most-Unit-Testing-is-Waste.pdf) of all this

Comment: @PaulEvans: -1 for that paper you linked to. I certainly wouldn't hire the author as a consultant. He appears to judge the value of unit testing mostly on experiences of unit testing gone wrong. Either he does this intentionally, in which case the paper is next to worthless because all we can say is that he has judged improper ("bad") unit testing to be a waste (which is no big surpise). Or he simply doesn't know better, in which case the paper is *also* worthless, because it's not credible: it's written by someone who doesn't even know what proper unit testing looks like.

Comment: @stakx I'd like to know what makes you more experienced than [James Coplien](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jim_Coplien).

Comment: I don't know why you think I'm more experienced than that guy. What I am or not is completely off-topic here. I don't know the guy, and I am not judging *him*, but his paper (based on the teaching and experiences that I've had). IMHO the paper is mostly a waste of time, for the reason mentioned. I could've gone into detail, but discussing that paper in detail would also be off-topic WRT to the question asked here. My intention was to warn readers without any experience of unit testing that the paper may have issues and shouldn't be taken as gospel without checking other authorative sources.

Comment: @PaulEvans: That said, I concede that I shouldn't have written "I wouldn't hire the author as a consultant." That *is* a judgment of him based solely on one paper, which seems unfair. I should have written: "If that paper is representative of the author's other writings, I wouldn't hire him."

Comment: @stakx Thanks for that, that's exactly what I was calling you out on.  I strongly believe in and use testing at every level of development. But that paper is challenging and hopefully reminds us that there's [no silver bullet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_Silver_Bullet) in our field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I am unsure of what my unit tests should cover.*

Maybe it helps to look at unit tests as a specification (runnable documentation!) for your code.

- What is considered valid input?
- What happens when the code is given valid input? Does it produce the expected output? (Don't just test one valid input value; focus on maybe 1 typical case, then all edge cases and extremes that should still *just* work.)
- What happens when the code is given invalid input? Are the expected errors / error codes produced?
- What environment is the code dependent on?
- What happens when that environment isn't properly set up?

The last two points are actually special cases of the first three. That's because unit tests don't necessarily test single, isolated functions:

- "Input" doesn't just have to be a function argument. It can be any kind of program state that your code will read (i.e. depends on).
- In the same way, "output" is not just a return value of a function. It can be any variable or program state that your code modifies.
- Your unit tests might not test just one single isolated function, but the interplay between several functions that must called in sequence to get something done. Read as documentation/specification, such a unit test would suggest that calling the functions in that order is an appropriate or even suggested way to get some task done.

> *Should I also check the value of each variable every time it is modified?*

Unit tests are completely separate from what they are testing (often called the System Under Test, abbreviated to SUT). That is, your unit tests should be separate functions wherein you set up the SUT, exercise it, and then check the outcome against the expected result.

Therefore your unit test functions will be very simple:

- set up the input for your SUT.
- call/exercise the SUT.
- read the output of the SUT and compare against expected output.

As you can see, there's not much room in such a simple procedure for variables that will change their value all the time. If you *have* such a unit test, chances are that it's too complex and you might want to change it, e.g. split it up.

Changing variables are more likely seen in the tested code (i.e. in the SUT) itself. But that's not where you put your test logic. That goes into a completely separate function, which makes up your unit test.

(Note that I'm speaking very generally, since you haven't said what framework you are using for your unit tests, so I might be slightly off on some issues.)